# How to limit size of the data on the server side a user can fetch in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I gave a talk about basics of Firebase (http://szimek.github.io/presentation-firebase-intro) at our local meetup and got 2 interesting questions from the audience.

Imagine you have a Twitter-like app with billion of tweets and everyone has read access to them.

1. Is there a way to limit size of the data (on the server side) a user can fetch? Even if I have `tweetsRef.limit(10)` call, a user could easily change it to `tweetsRef.limit(10e9)` and try to fetch all tweets.
2. How to prevent users from updating existing records (even if it was created by that user), but allow them to delete existing records (only if it was created by that user)?

Comment: Please ask a single question at a time on SO. Two disparate questions will make it difficult to evaluate "correct" or "useful" answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about limit manipulation you could just fetch the tweets on your server instead of the client (as you suggested) so users can't manipulate the limits.

For your second question, it depends on how you want to handle deletion. Often you don't actually want the object deleted, so you could just give the creating user write access on the `deleted` attribute. Alternatively, if you want them to actually delete the object, check to see that the user is the creator and that the value of [`newData`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/newdata.html) is `null`.

Here is an example security rule from @Kato's comment below (writes/deletes allowed, updates prevented):

```
".write": "!data.exits() || !newData.exists()"
```

Comment: This would allow deletes but no updates: `".write": "!data.exits() || !newData.exists()"`

Comment: So there's no way to limit size of the data user can fetch on Firebase side? It looks like it should be relatively easy for malicious users to use up all available transfer for specific app types (like Twitter clone).

Comment: @Kato wasn't that the goal?

Comment: I think so. Just enhancing your response.

Comment: Cool just making sure.